# PL/SQL Use table variable as query table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

In PL/SQL is it possible to use a variable as a query a table?

Tried:

```sql
declare
   TYPE t_name IS TABLE OF varchar(50) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   v_names t_name;
begin
select name bulk collect into v_names from my_table;

select name from v_names where name = 'Max';
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ... but not how you are doing it, for two reasons:

- Firstly, you do not have a collection (what you are calling a table variable) as you have used `INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER` so what you have is an associative array.
- Secondly, you can only use collections in SQL queries where the data type has been declared in the SQL scope (and yours is declared in PL/SQL).

So, first you need to create the type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t_name IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

Then you can run the PL/SQL block:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_names t_name;
  v_name  VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  SELECT name
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_names
  FROM my_table;

  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
  INTO   v_name
  FROM   TABLE(v_names)
  WHERE  COLUMN_VALUE = 'Max';
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_name );
END;
/
```

*(Note: the table collection expression in the second query has the pseudo-column `COLUMN_VALUE` rather than any particular identifier from a table.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=127829d049d85342589b984b57234690)*

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why they make this so complicated, I don't want to trash the database with types everywhere :/  Just want it to work! If someone drops my type it will break the system, god damn.

Comment: @user5507535 If you want to filter the collection to find a single value then you can do it in the initial `SELECT` to only get a single value or you can use a `FOR` loop to iterate over the collection in PL/SQL and then you don't need to try to put it back into the SQl scope.

Comment: @user5507535. It is not complicated, it is just unfamiliar to you. As far a trashing the database that not an issue. In 20 years I never had a type dropped. After all varchar2, integer, date are all defined as TYPE (well mostly sub-types) in the package STANDARD.  So doing it that way is consistent.   Just different.

Comment: @Belayer I understand you, but this design decision makes no sense, it's like asking for you to create a global variable when you don't need to. I would only use the type on that very specific file and scope, so why need to have if shared globally in the whole system? There are many things in PL/SQL and SQL that are like this, in my opinion, it's bad design and not ergonomic for the programmer.

Comment: @user5507535 It makes perfect sense if you consider that they are two different languages. It is like writing a Java program that wraps some low-level C code and asking why when I declare a data-type in Java can I not use it in the C code? You cannot because they are two different languages and the wrapping is from Java to C and not the other way round. It is the same for PL/SQL and SQL; you can use SQL types in PL/SQL but you cannot use PL/SQL types in SQL.

Comment: @user5507535 *"If someone drops my type it will break the system"* If someone drops the CUSTOMERS table it will break the system. You'd hope that questions would be asked about the pre-release testing.